# Why does Visual Studio start the Pen and Touch driver?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, touch

I have an aging laptop with a shoddy mouse pad (the mouse cursor literally erratically and randomly jumps around). It's one of those convertible laptops that also allows pen input. The pen input is based on a windows service. So I disabled the service and use an external USB mouse.

For whatever reason, when I start VS2010 and do something with it, like debug/edit/run/etc..., the IDE will actually start the Pen/Touch driver.  Here is proof that it was started by VS2010, with the description of what this driver is.

From Process Explorer:

[image]

From Task Mananger

[image]

Any idea as to why this is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: VS2010 is built on WPF.  WPF supports pen and touch input at its core so this is not entirely a surprise.  There is no "i've got a crappy laptop" setting in VS, you probably have to disable this in the Windows configuration.  No idea where, I'd look in Control Panel first.  Superuser.com is the best place to ask.

Comment: @GagandeepSingh My kids made me an account, so don't accidentally see what they are doing on the computer :)